# $(this) not working within .append()

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, this

I'm trying to run this piece of code

```
$('.post').not('.compose').append('<a class = "card_mark hover" onclick = "addToDeck(\''+$('input[name=token]').val()+'\','+$(this).attr("id")+');return false"></a>');
```

But the `$(this).attr("id");` is returning `undefined`.

I can't quite figure this out. Could anyone help?

Comment: what do you expect `this` to be?

Comment: What is your code context?

Comment: what are you expecting `this` to be? It isn't anything on that line of code

Comment: the ID attribute of the element .post

Comment: Well `this` in that context is window or whatever scope that is executed in. Has nothing to do with post. You would need to use an each to get the context of post.

Comment: @Frank it doesn't work that way. If it was inside a callback perhaps but on a line like that `this` will be scoped before that line

Answer (score 1):

It would be better to do this instead by using event delegation and not using inline-js especially when jQuery is included.

```
var elm = $('.post').not('.compose');
elm.on('click', 'a', function(){
   addToDeck($('input[name=token]').val()+'\','+ $(this).closest('.post').attr("id"));
   return false;
});
```

Now, you've bound the event. Now append just append the `<a>`

```
elm.append('<a />', { "class" : "card_mark hover" });
```

Comment: that doesn't append the element

Comment: @charlietfl it doesn't before my edit. But I had just advised "Now you can append" Any way added the code too.

Comment: the `this` is wrong also, not what the OP is after.

Comment: @epascarello ok. I see OP wants .post's id. Edited.

Answer (score 0):

To demonstrate how to keep same structure that you have now you can use an `each` loop so you can isolate instances of `$('.post')` in order to work with it to help create the html and have `this` be what you had hoped it was .

```
$('.post').not('.compose').each(function(){
   /* now "this" is the individual element with class=post */
   $(this).append('<a class = "card_mark hover" onclick = "addToDeck(\''+$('input[name=token]').val()+'\','+$(this).attr("id")+');return false"></a>');

});
```